# ASP.NET Membership Provider with Confirmation email

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

Is there any framework/library for using ASP.NET Membership Provider with confirmation email, something ready to be used ?

Standard functionality used on almost all public web sites.

Comment: How did you finally decide to implement this?  Would you update your post with what worked best for you?  Thanks.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer. It is mine. :) 
This was the most simplest and good explained solution.

Comment: Oops.  Thanks for pointing out the obvious.  :-)

Comment: You might find this answer also useful.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc/7796280#7796280

Comment: You might find this answer also useful.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793108/where-to-find-c-sharp-sample-code-to-implement-password-recovery-in-asp-net-mvc/7796280#7796280

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found good example:

[4Guys from Rolla : Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616110844/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx)