# ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Membership: implementing email address validation after user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 2 site, where I want to have users verify their email address after they register.

I want to send an email to the address with a link that the user can click to verify their email, and then handle the clicking of that link (the link will contain a specific id, of course).

Of course, this is **easy to manually implement**, but **is there anything already built in to ASP.NET that has such a function?**

Comment: Similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424154/asp-net-membership-provider-with-confirmation-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already described in the comment from jim Lamb, their is no built in functionality in the memberShip provider.  In 1 of my previous jobs, I followed the example given by the guys from Rolla -  [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616110844/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/062508-1.aspx) .

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing and came across this:
http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/